# How to change angular mat icon button color based on condition?

Tags: angular

How to change angular button color based on condition ? , this is a mat icon button

#code

```
<div class="flex">
  <button mat-icon-button *ngFor="let action of actions" 
    [disabled]="isDisabled && action.name === 'For Approval'" matTooltip="{{action.name}}"
    (click)="clickActionBtn(action.name)">
    <mat-icon style="font-size: 20px;" class="{{action.class}}">
      {{action.icon}}
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
```

I tried , but it does not work

[class.gray]="isDisabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular Material `mat-icon` takes `color` as an input (with `primary`, `accent`, and `warn` options based on your material theme colors) to define the color of the icon, so you need to use this input to change it, like the following:

```html
<!-- `color` input allowed options are: `primary`, `accent`, and `warn` only. -->
<mat-icon [color]="isDisabled && action.name === 'For Approval' ? 'primary' : ''"></mat-icon>
```

So you can update your button HTML to be like the following:

```html
<button
  mat-icon-button
  *ngFor="let action of actions"
  [disabled]="isDisabled && action.name === 'For Approval'"
  matTooltip="{{action.name}}"
  (click)="clickActionBtn(action.name)"
>
  <mat-icon
    style="font-size: 20px"
    [color]="isDisabled && action.name === 'For Approval' ? 'primary' : ''"
  >
    {{action.icon}}
  </mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: and how would that be based on condition ? I only want to change the color icon of the button if condition is true

Comment: I updated my answer to include a condition.

Comment: how do I insert this condition isDisabled && action.name === 'For Approval'

Comment: Check it now, please.

Comment: I am using the class with the color , https://imgur.com/a/t2iic01 , it is possible that we add the color on the  json config ?

Comment: the problem with your implementation is that it changes the rest of the button

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify more?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aS0pQ3b , THE Colors of the button came from the json config I sent you above the imgur link , I dont wanna remove the class like you did it will remove the other buttons color , I only want to change the color based on the condition which is isDisabled && action.name === 'For Approval'

Comment: Check it now, please. And you can adjust it as you want after that. Thanks.